# building a web scraping using the selenium command

Tags: selenium, xpath, web-scraping, time, webdriver

I'm building a web scraping using the selenium command. I was able to read the data from the table on the first and second pages, however, I cannot read the data on the following pages. Can anybody help me?

Below is the code I am using.

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[@class='painel'
> and 1]/td[2]/a[1 and @href='javascript:pesquisar(2);']"}   (Session
> info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.75)

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import json

url = 'https://www.desaparecidos.pr.gov.br/desaparecidos/desaparecidos.do?action=iniciarProcesso&m=false'
option = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep (5)
lista = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list_tabela"]/tbody')
lista_text = lista.text
print (lista_text)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[@class='painel' and 1]/td[2]/a[1 and @href='javascript:pesquisar(2);']").click()
time.sleep (5)
lista = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list_tabela"]/tbody')
lista_text = lista.text
print (lista_text)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[@class='painel' and 1]/td[2]/a[3 and @href='javascript:pesquisar(3);']").click()
time.sleep (10)
lista = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list_tabela"]/tbody')
lista_text = lista.text
print (lista_text)
```

Comment: use waits not just sleeps.

Comment: There is no need to use `time.sleep` if you use `driver.implicitly_wait`. Also you can use it only once in code - no need to add line multiple times